# How to iterate over a map in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a map that I am passing to pug on my server but I am unable to iterate over the key value pairs in the map in order to render the data in the map. I have tried simplifying the map down but still can't get it to work.

```
router.get('url', middlware(),(req,res)=>{
  let renderData = {};
  renderData.test = new Map([["1","one"],["2","two"]]);
  res.render('template', renderData);
})
```

template:

```
block content
  .container
    .mt-3.whiteBG
      each item in test
        p here is some text
```

In the simplified version I can't even get plain text to render, let alone access the values of the map within the iteration. I am able to access the values if I do something like this `p #{test.get("1")}`
Are maps just not iterable in Pug? If not is there a way for me to convert my map into an array/object that Pug can iterate through?

Comment: Try either `new Map([["1","one"],["2","two"]]).values()` or `new Map([["1","one"],["2","two"]]).entries()`, based on your requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pug will [support iteration over ES6 collections in the next release](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/3170#issuecomment-531795244). Until then, you can convert the Map to an object using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
renderData.test = Object.fromEntries(renderData.test);
```

Comment: That looks like it works with the simplified version! I'll try using it tonight for the full Map. Thank you!

Comment: Of note- older versions of Node do not support the Object.fromEntries() function. I had to update the Node server my client is using to utilize this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since Pug v2.1 you can iterate your map like this:

```
 - const map = new Map([["1","one"],["2","two"]]);
 each [key, value] of map
   p= key + ': ' + value
```

Output

```
1: one
2: two
```

[Source](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/pull/3179)

> Support `each ... of ...` loops
>
> ```
> each value of iterable
>   li= value
> ```
>
> This requires an environment that supports the for (const val of
> iterable) syntax in JS. You can iterate over Maps, Sets etc. as well
> as arrays. There is also some destructuring of map keys:
>
> ```
> - const map = new Map([['a', 'x'], ['b', 'y']]);
> each [key, value] of map
>   li
>     strong= key
>     = value
> ```